# javascript trying to remove all things with certain tags

Tags: javascript, tags

I'm trying to use javascript to remove everyhting with button or input tags from a page... So far my code removes some of them and I dont know why. It only removes one checkbox out of many, and 2 buttons (there are 3 buttons)

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length ; j++)
{
    buttons[j].parentNode.removeChild(buttons[j]);
}

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length ; j++)
{
    checkboxes[j].parentNode.removeChild(checkboxes[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length ; j++) // You use the wrong variable here
{
    checkboxes[j].parentNode.removeChild(checkboxes[j]);
}
```

Should be;

```
for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length ; j++)
```

Regarding to the undeleted button, maybe it's because it's an `input type="button"` and not a `<button>`?

Note that `document.getElementsByTagName("input");` will get and delete later all the inputs, not just the checkboxes!

---

May I suggest you using a javascript library like jQuery? you could have done this will one line of code with no problems:

```
$('input[type="button"], input[type="checkbox"], button').remove();
```

Comment: AaaaH!!! thats the second time I've posted something here today beacuse I misspelled length!!!! I must be tired. Thanks!!

Comment: @grizzly_beer. LOL. Just pay attention to the other issues as well... Good luck!

Comment: oh wait, that wasnt it... I am tired... :/

Comment: @grizzly_beer. It sure was it, but you may have other problems outside the code you pasted here. Try jQuery, it can save you from trouble, specially, if you're not a javascript ninja.

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a *live* [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList). That means, when you remove the first element, a) the length decreases and b) the (first) item of the list is shifted.

There are two possibilities to work around that:

- always remove the last element. The NodeList is in document order, so that will work:

  ```
  for (var i=buttons.length-1; i>=0; i--) // var i=buttons.length; while(i--)
      buttons[i].parentNode.removeChild(buttons[i]);
  ```
- always remove the first element, and don't run an index until the `length`:

  ```
  while (buttons.length) // > 0
      buttons[0].parentNode.removeChild(buttons[0]);
  ```

It also would work with jQuery and co, because they copy the NodeList items in a static array. You can do that yourself as well:

```
var staticButtons = Array.prototype.slice.call(buttons);
for (var i=0; i<staticButtons.length; i++)
    staticButtons[i].parentNode.removeChild(staticButtons[i]);
```

or you use a document selection method that returns a static NodeList right away, like `querySelector`:

```
var staticList = document.querySelectorAll("button, input");
```